# Is this a valid answer for this set theory problem: "Prove that if A ⊊ B, then B \ A ≠ ∅"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Problem: Prove that if $ A \subsetneq B$, then $ B/A \ne \emptyset$

I just started studying set theory and mathematical logic and would like to know if the following could be considered a valid answer for the problem above:

$$ A\subsetneq B \Rightarrow A=\{x:x\in B\} \space \land \space A \ne B $$
$$ A\ne B \Rightarrow A\cap B\ne B $$
$$B/A = \{x:x\in B \space \land \space x\notin B\cap A\} \space \land \space B\cap A \ne B \Rightarrow B/A \ne \emptyset $$

Comment: I think it's wrong the second line and then you write $B/A$ but should be $B$ \ $A$

Comment: You are right, the second line is wrong, thanks a lot for the help